# Como criar um link que ao ser clicado muda o valor do href=" "?

Tags: jquery

Estou criando um botão para abrir o chat em um dos meus sites. Atualmente estou utilizando o Zopim.

Para abrir o chat, é utilizado o link:

```
<a href="javascript:void($zopim.livechat.window.show())">ABRIR CHAT</a>
```

Para fechar o chat, é utilizado o link:

```
<a href="javascript:void($zopim.livechat.window.hide())">FECHAR CHAT</a>
```

Preciso que **quando** a pessoa clicar para `Abrir o Chat`, automaticamente o link mude para `Fechar o Chat` e que quando a pessoa clicar em `Fechar o Chat` mude para `Abrir o Chat`.

Ou seja, fica alternando, quando clica em um o link muda para o outro.

Assim com o mesmo botão eu posso abrir e fechar o chat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem várias maneiras de fazer isso. Eu evitaria JavaScript inline (dentro do href ou outro atributo). Algo assim seria mais limpo:

```
<a id="botao-chat" href="#">ABRIR CHAT</a>
<script>
var aberto = false;
$('#botao-chat').click(function() {
    if(aberto) {
        $(this).text('ABRIR CHAT');
        $zopim.livechat.window.hide();
    } else {
        $(this).text('FECHAR CHAT');
        $zopim.livechat.window.show();
    }
    aberto = !aberto;
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Não tem como ser só 1 link não? Pois é 1 botão, o mesmo teria que abrir e fechar. :(

Comment: No jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandreBR/g8r7wveo/1/

Comment: Exemplo: http://iweb.com/dedicated-server quando você clica em `LIVE CHAT` no canto inferior direito, ele abre e fecha o chat deles.

Comment: Nem vi que você editou a resposta! hehe! Tá ficando muito bom, só que tem um problema: Quando clica em ABRIR CHAT, ele muda o texto para FECHAR CHAT, mais se clicar em FECHAR CHAT, ele não muda o texto de volta.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandreBR/g8r7wveo/2/

Comment: Abra o console do seu browser e veja o erro. O zopim precisa estar carregado (seja lá o que ele for).

Comment: Sim! verdade, agora está 100%! resposta certa!

Comment: Ficou 100% Vlw, ficou melhor ainda porque o link fica `href="#"` aí não fica o link do zopim.

Comment: É que eu não tinha me tocado que precisava do zopim funcionando. Eu coloquei no jsFiddle e não tava funcionando. Rsrsrs

Comment: se não fosse pedir muito, você poderia citar outro exemplo? Tipo, ao invés de abrir e fechar o chat, fosse adicionado um `margin-top:20px;` quando clicasse.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes Aí já tá virando outra pergunta... Dá uma olhada em http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2

Comment: Vou fazer outra pergunta então. Não corre risco de darem minha pergunta como duplicada não? Eu queria que quando clicasse no link `<a>` fosse dado um `margin-top:20px;` na `div` que contém a classe `.zopim`

Comment: Pronto @bfavaretto http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28634/como-criar-um-link-que-ao-ser-clicado-muda-%C3%A9-adicionada-uma-propriedade-css-em-u

Answer (score 0):

Olá amigo para mudar o valor do href no click utilize a propriedade `setAttribute`

veja um exemplo:

```
<a href="#" id="AbrirChat">ABRIR CHAT</a>
<a href="#" id="FecharChat">FECHAR CHAT</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("FecharChat").onclick = function() {
   var link = document.getElementById("AbrirChat");
   link.setAttribute("href", "abrir.html");
   return false;
   }
</script>
```

nesse exemplo a propriedade href do ABRIR CHAT muda assim que você clicar em FECHAR CHAT.

Comment: Você não entendeu, eu quero que seja alternado os links! Quando clica em `A` ele muda para `B` e quando clica em `B` ele muda para `A`. No caso será apenas **1** link, onde a pessoa pode abrir e fechar o chat.