# Como criar um link que ao ser clicado seja adicionado uma propriedade CSS em uma div?

Tags: jquery

> Tenho uma `div` em meu site com a classe `.zopim`, como posso fazer para quando a pessoa clicar  no link `div` com classe `.zopim` receba um `margin-bottom:20px` ?

Tipo assim: Quando a pessoa clicar em:

```
<a id="botão-chat" href="#">ABRIR CHAT</a>
```

Seja adicionada à `div` o **margin-bottom**.

Do mesmo modo, se a pessoa clicar novamente no link, seja removido o **margin-bottom** que foi adicionado.

Link de uma pergunta semelhante: [Como criar um link que ao ser clicado muda o valor do href=" "?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28626/como-criar-um-link-que-ao-ser-clicado-muda-o-valor-do-href)

Comment: Pelo proprio exemplo que o @bfavaretto postou, você pode usar `$('seu elemento').css(...)` ou `$( 'seu elemento' ).addClass( 'classe-com-margin' ) | $( 'seu elemento' ).removeClass`( 'classe-sem-margin' )

Comment: Não sei muito jQuery. Faça do seu comentário uma resposta @PapaCharlie você é o cara.

Comment: Papa, tá aí? rs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A maneira mais limpa para fazer isso é com classe CSS.

Defina uma classe CSS, exemplo:

```
.aberto {
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

Aí quando o link fôr clicado pode adicionar essa classe no `div.zopim`. Para poder adicionar e remover, é mais simples usar o .toggleClass()

Eu faria assim:

```
$('.zopim a').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.zopim').toggleClass('aberto');
});
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/834moahb/

Explicação do código:

- `$('.zopim a')` seleciona todos os links dentro de `.zopim`
- `.on('click', function(){` quando esse(s) link receber click correr uma função
- `$(this).closest('.zopim').toggleClass('aberto');` partindo do elemento clicado (`this`) procura nos pais por um elemento com classe `.zopim` e faz toggle da classe. Aqui podia usar também `.parent()` em vez de closest no caso de a o link ser descendente direto de div. Mas o closest é mais seguro não sabendo o seu HTML exato.

---

Se quiser também juntar texto como vi na sua resposta pode fazer assim:

```
$('.zopim a').on('click', function () {
    var zopim = $(this).closest('.zopim');
    var chatAberto = zopim.hasClass('aberto');
    zopim.toggleClass('aberto');
    this.innerHTML = chatAberto ? 'Abrir chat.' : 'Fechar chat';
});
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/834moahb/2/

Comment: Boa dica. É possível incrementar para alterar o texto do elemento com `$(this).text('ABRIR CHAT')` ou `$(this).text('FECHAR CHAT')`?

Comment: @PapaCharlie isso não faz parte da pergunta, mas faria assim: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/834moahb/1/

Comment: Muito bacana!!! @Sergio você poderia citar também outro exemplo? Veja: http://pastebin.com/CttAi3R8 com esse código, é adicionado `margin-top`. É possível fazer uma espécie de transição? Semelhante ao que você fez com o `margin` no CSS? Só que com jQuery ? Aí poderei dar resposta como certa ^.^

Comment: @AlexandreLopes a razão da minha resposta é que acho que é melhor fazer isto com classes e CSS no CSS, não CSS no javascript. Quanto menos jQuery tiver na página melhor.

Comment: Mas com CSS fica todo mal feito e não funcionou aqui. Outra coisa só roda em navegadores atualizados. Vou dar melhor resposta e vou esperar por seu exemplo com `JS` mesmo.

Comment: É com o `Closure` que faz isso?

Answer (score 7):

Você pode usar o método `.css()` do JQuery

Um exemplo que você pode usar junto com a resposta da outra pergunta seria:

```
<a id="botao-chat" href="#">ABRIR CHAT</a>
<div id="a">
    <p>texto</p>
</div>

<script>
var aberto = false;
$('#botao-chat').click(function() {
if(aberto) {
    $(this).text('ABRIR CHAT');
    $zopim.livechat.window.hide();
    $('#a').css("margin-top", "0");
} else {
    $(this).text('FECHAR CHAT');
    $zopim.livechat.window.show();
    $('#a').css("margin-top", "50px");
}
aberto = !aberto;
return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Você tá intendendo errado @SilasRibeiro nessa minha pergunta não será preciso utilizar `$zopim.livechat.window`. Mas obrigado por tentar ajudar. Vou dar um +1 pela força.

Comment: nesse caso você só precisa tirar o $zopim.livechat.window

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um exemplo simples onde o controle é baseado no texto do elemento, sem o controle por variáveis - é apenas mais uma possibilidade já que você controla o texto pelo jQuery.
http://jsfiddle.net/p537yrcp/1/

```
$('#botao-chat').click(function()
{
    if( $(this).text() === 'ABRIR CHAT' )
    {
        $(this).text( 'FECHAR CHAT' )
        $(this).css({ 'margin': '10px' });
    } else{
        $(this).text( 'ABRIR CHAT' )
        $(this).css({ 'margin': '0px' });
    }
});
```

Comment: Legal Papa, bacana....

Comment: Vai dar certinho com um outro botão que estou criando, vlw papa!!!!!! Ainda sou bem iniciante em jQuery :(

Comment: jQuery não domino muito bem ainda, mas que bom que serviu

Answer (score 0):

Resposta editada de @SilasRibeiro

Não sei muita coisa de jQuery, mas só segui a lógica.

> Eu apenas mudei algumas coisas, como de `margin` para `padding`, troquei o `ID #a` para a `Classe .zopim`, e removi o `$zopim.livechat.window`.

Código final e funcional:

```
    // Abrir e Fechar o CHAT
    var aberto = false;
$('#botao-chat').click(function() {
if(aberto) {
    $(this).text('ABRIR CHAT');
    $('div.zopim').css("margin-bottom", "0");
} else {
    $(this).text('FECHAR CHAT');
    $('div.zopim').css("margin-bottom", "50px");
}
aberto = !aberto;
return false;
});
```

E o legal é que posso adaptá-lo e utilizá-lo em outras coisas.

Obs: Não vou colocar essa como melhor resposta, apesar de ser. Pois acho que o @SilasRibeiro tem mais direito do que eu. Então essa pergunta vai ficar sem melhor resposta.